# May I use groupby to solve this case in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, redis, python-2.x

I have a redis database that it's receiving data from Arduino every ten seconds.

Now, I want to make six ten-second data calculate one sixty-second data and then get avg, max, min of six ten-second data as follow.

```
import json

a = [u'{"id":"proximity_sensor1","tstamp":1440643570238,"avg":15.0,"coefVariation":0.0,"anom":0,"max":15.0,"min":15.0,"sample_size":10}',
 u'{"id":"proximity_sensor1","tstamp":1440643580307,"avg":15.0,"coefVariation":0.0,"anom":0,"max":15.0,"min":15.0,"sample_size":9}',
 u'{"id":"proximity_sensor1","tstamp":1440643590242,"avg":15.0,"coefVariation":0.0,"anom":0,"max":15.0,"min":15.0,"sample_size":9}',
 u'{"id":"proximity_sensor1","tstamp":1440643590242,"avg":15.0,"coefVariation":0.0,"anom":0,"max":15.0,"min":15.0,"sample_size":8}',
 u'{"id":"proximity_sensor1","tstamp":1440643590242,"avg":15.0,"coefVariation":0.0,"anom":0,"max":15.0,"min":15.0,"sample_size":9}',
 u'{"id":"proximity_sensor1","tstamp":1440643590242,"avg":15.0,"coefVariation":0.0,"anom":0,"max":15.0,"min":15.0,"sample_size":9}']

a = map(lambda x: json.loads(x), a)

#print a

def abc(aaa):
    for index in range(0, len(aaa), 6):
        abc = aaa[index:(index+6)]
        tuples = [('avg', 'max', 'min')]
        avg = sum(map(lambda x: x['avg'], abc))/6
        min_ = min(map(lambda x: x['min'], abc))
        max_ = max(map(lambda x: x['max'], abc))
        yield [avg, max_, min_]

print list(abc(a))
```

I am thinking whether it has better method to solve or not. If I use `itertools.groupby`, may I solve it faster? or anyone has good idea to simplify calculated process?

Comment: You are simply taking a group of 6 elements right? not based on any particular condition?

Comment: Yes, you're right. You can't care meaning of 6 elements. I just care how to simplify calculated process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally itertools.groupby is used with some condition to group the elements , but since in your case you are not having any such conditions , instead you just want to group every 6 elements together, I don't think using itertools.groupby would give any benefit.

That being said there are some other improvements I can suggest -

1. You can use the 'key' argument for max/min functions rather than your current method of map/lambda , Example -

   ```
   max_ = max(abc, key= lambda x:x['max'])['max']
   ```

   Similarly for min() function.
2. Also , I think it would be more readable to have a list comprehension for sum() , rather than map/lambda . Example -

   ```
    avg = sum([x['avg'] for x in abc])/6
   ```